# Maximum number of MySQL connections, apprpriately closing connections

Tags: mysql, multithreading

I am working on a web app (small parts) and I was looking at the way the program handles MySQL connections.  Put a little debugging code in to just monitor the status, and I get something like this:

```
$query = 'SHOW STATUS WHERE variable_name LIKE "Threads_%" OR variable_name = "Connections"';
$result = mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], $query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo print_r($row);
}
```

Array ( [0] => Connections [Variable_name] => Connections [1] => 1368 [Value] => 1368 ) 1Array ( [0] => Threads_cached [Variable_name] => Threads_cached [1] => 0 [Value] => 0 ) 1Array ( [0] => Threads_connected [Variable_name] => Threads_connected [1] => 1 [Value] => 1 ) 1Array ( [0] => Threads_created [Variable_name] => Threads_created [1] => 1367 [Value] => 1367 ) 1Array ( [0] => Threads_running [Variable_name] => Threads_running [1] => 1 [Value] => 1 ) 1

The Connection and Threads created continually increment, but the threads running always remains at one.  I looked at SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_user_connections' on the server and it is set to 0.  Is that a problem to have so many connections and threads created ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Variables **Connections** and **Threads_created** are always incrementing counters. If you want to see current connections - use **Threads_connected** variable, or issue the query `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST`.